# Plotting shapes form Census Bureau with GeoPandas results in some erroneous white triangles

Tags: geopandas, census

GeoPandas 0.6.1

Almost every shapefile from Census Bureau is giving the same error.

In this case is the Block data shapes from Maine. The file is "tl_2019_23_tabblock10.shp"

```
gdf.plot(figsize=(32, 16), column='INTPTLAT10', linewidth = 0)
```

[image]

EDIT: full code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import descartes
import geopandas as gp

from shapely.geometry import Polygon

sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)
sns.mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(10,6))
%matplotlib inline

shp_path = "./tl_2019_23_tabblock10/tl_2019_23_tabblock10.shp"
sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)

def read_shapefile(sf):

    fields = [x[0] for x in sf.fields][1:]
    records = sf.records()
    shps = [s.points for s in sf.shapes()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields, data=records)
    df = df.assign(coords=shps)
    return df

df = read_shapefile(sf)

df.INTPTLAT10 = df.INTPTLAT10.astype(float)
df.INTPTLON10 = df.INTPTLON10.astype(float)
df.STATEFP10 = df.STATEFP10.astype(int)

df.coords = [Polygon(list(i)) for i in df.coords]
gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.coords)

gdf.plot(figsize=(32, 16), column='INTPTLAT10', linewidth = 0)
```

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Comment: I was making a mistake, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was using read_shapefile(sf) function that I got from a tutorial somewhere to upload data into a DataFrame, then make a GeoDataFrame from the DataFrame. That was a mistake.

This is the correct code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import geopandas as gpenter code here

sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)
sns.mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(10,6))
%matplotlib inline

df = gp.read_file("./tl_2019_23_tabblock10/tl_2019_23_tabblock10.shp")

df.INTPTLAT10 = df.INTPTLAT10.astype(float)
df.plot(figsize=(24, 12), column='INTPTLAT10', linewidth = 0)
```

And the map without the weird looking white triangles.

[image]